# How to update and access subkeys of a dict in a dict [python]

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using a dict in a dict to count four parameters related to 20 items.

```
resi = {'a': {'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0}, 'b': {'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0}, ...}
```

The function 'count' counts the frequency of parameters x, y, z occurring with 20 items.

`re`: a key in main dict `resi`; `bas` : a key in the nested dict

```
def count(re, bas, aa = resi) :
    t = aa[re] 
    t[bas] += 1
    print aa
```

When the function is called, `count` updates the parameter in all main keys. I also tried

```
aa[re][0][bas] += 1
```

This shows a key error. How do I update a specific key in main dict?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do here. What are the values you pass into `count()`?

Comment: re and bas are strings four characters long! Does that affect ?

Comment: It sounds as if each nested dict is a copy of *one* dict instead of separate objects.

Comment: Are you saying that if you update `resi['a']['x']`, that `resi['b']['x']` also changes? If so, please share the code that *created* the `resi` to start with.

Comment: Yes I created `resi` from `dict.fromkeys(res, second_dict)` and `resi[b][x]` also changes when I change `resi[a][x]`.

Comment: All your values point to *one* mutable dict, and then what you see is expected behaviour. Use Ignacio's technique to create a new dict for each value (use `dict(second_dict)` in that loop to create a copy).

Comment: @Martijn I used `resi = dict((k, second_dict) for k in ('a', 'b', ...))` to create the dict, still ended up with the same results.

Comment: I've expanded my comment into an answer below. You need to create *copies* of `second_dict`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create *unique* dicts for the subdict, you cannot reuse the same `second_dict` value and expect this to result in separate dictionaries for your nested structure.

Use:

```
resi = {k: dict(second_dict) for k in res}
```

instead; `dict(second_dict)` creates a fresh copy of `second_dict` for each key.

Answer (score 2):

You goofed up creating the dict in the first place.

```
resi = dict((k, {'x':0, ...}) for k in ('a', 'b', ...))
```

Comment: How do I access each item in this dict? Same format I used before?